# how we can create metric filter for cloudwatch log filter for sagemaker training job failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

i am trying to create metric filter for sagemaker training job failure to set cloudwatch alarm as sagemaker training job failed give ExitCode = 1 so i am create metric filter for it .

before creating metric filter i checked  ExitCode = 1 query in log insights using this query

fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /ExitCode 1/
| sort @timestamp desc

this query is working fine i am getting sagemaker training job fails  but

when i create metric filter in cloudwatch log  with Filter pattern  ExitCode = 1 and test the pattern with cloudwatch log which contain sagemaker job failure with   ExitCode = 1  i am not getting  any result.

when i create metric filter in cloudwatch log  with Filter pattern  "ExitCode 1" and test the pattern with cloudwatch log which contain sagemaker job failure with   ExitCode = 1  i am not getting any result .  my requirement is to get fail job result
**
how i solve this issue plz suggest.**